# Translate paper-input label

Tags: html, json, polymer-2.x

I want to change the language on my labels on my paper-inputs.

```
        <paper-input label="Phone"></paper-input>
        <paper-input label="Email"></paper-input>
```

I have the translation in a json file like this:

```
  Polymer({
    attached: function () {
       this.loadResources(this.resolveUrl('locales.json'));
    },
  });
```

My locals.json file where I put my translations:

```
 {
  "en": {
    "hello": "Hello friend"
    },
  "sv": {
    "hello": "Hej kompis"
   }
 }
```

How can I translate my labels on the paper-input. Is it a easy way here that I miss? Thanks for your help. 
I dont have any problems to translate other stuff like the button here but that is not in the label:

```
 <div class="bookPickupButtonHolder">
    <paper-button toggles raised class="green">{{localize("hello")}}</paper-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
<paper-input label='{{localize("hello")}}'></paper-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

I think this should work

```
<paper-input label="localize('hello')"></paper-input>
```

Comment: I tried a bunch of stuff and tried your way to but it didn't work.